# The exeption UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000. occurred in some computers

Tags: c#, utc

I have the following `code` in an Windows Store Application using `C#` :

```
birthDateTimePicker.Date = DateTime.Now;
if (birthDateTimePicker.Date == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    no_date_lable.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    birthDateTimePicker.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Note : this line `birthDateTimePicker.Date = DateTime.Now;` is for example really user will selected or it will come from server.

But i get an exception in this line :

> if (dt_born_dt == DateTime.MinValue)

What is the reason for the exception thrown :

> The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between
>   year 0 and 10,000.

Really i tested this in three computers and i got error in one of them!!!

I changed the time zone of my system to (`UTC-08:00`) Pacific Time (US & Canada) and didn't get this exception at all and codes worked correctly!

My question is really why this exception occurred in the system that its time zone was (`UTC+03:30`) Tehran!

Sorry for my poor english

[image]

Comment: no, i saw this before, but i dont use DateTimeOffset

Comment: I don't get any exception _at all_. Are you sure you posted the right code example?

Comment: yes, just i get this "1985-01-23" from server in my code is it in this variable "patient_date_of_birth" and I tried this code in another computer really worked correctly!!!

Comment: `dt_born_dt` is *not* a simple `DateTime` variable. It is some GUI control. It has a property `Visibility`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen that's nasty, whoever decided to use this name for a control.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Wow, really? o.O And _still_ it has an implicit conversation from `System.DateTime` to it.

Comment: You should post the stack trace for the exception as well. I am not sure if it comes from the line indicated or from the `catch` block above it.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen  but i commented all of bellow code in if statment

Comment: Non-reproducible. Read [ask] and create a [mcve]. As @Jeppe indicates, `dt_born_dt` is not of type `System.DateTime`. Internally, the control will use a `DateTimeOffset`, where the date you pass will be converted from `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` to `DateTimeKind.UTC`, where it'll become < `DateTime.MinValue` (assuming you're in a GMT+ timezone). The fix probably is `dt_born_dt = DateTime.MinValue.SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.UTC)`.

Comment: okey i will show its happend

Comment: i posted new photo of this exception, I tested in 3 computers and really this error occurred in tow of them !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CodeCaster answer was very complete and helpful. However, another way to tackle this problem is to convert the "DateTime.MinValue" to **UTC**.

```
if (birthDateTimePicker.Date == DateTime.MinValue.ToUniversalTime())
```

I had to use this method because "birthDateTimePicker.Date" type in my DB is DateTime and not DateTimeOffset, and I did't want to convert it.

Thank you all my friends.

Comment: This is not a good solution. Maybe it works on your machine (whose clock is ahead of Greenwich, western hemisphere) because `ToUniversalTime()` avoids exceptions. But will it work on the western hemisphere? In zone -06:00, say, will this create a date and time corresponding to 0001/01/01 00:06:00?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I tested many of timezone and didn't get exception, its saved in my DB with 0001/01/01 00:00:00,did i make a mistake?

Answer (score 4):

So your control `dt_born_dt` (please use meaningful names like `birthDateTimePicker`, and consider that birthdates don't need a time and most certainly can't be of year 1 [there are no people of age ~2015 alive right now], perhaps use a nullable type) has a `Date` property that is of type `DateTimeOffset`, which is visible from the `+3:30` value the debugger shows.

Now this type has an implicit conversion from `DateTime`, so if you do this:

```
birthDatePicker.Date = DateTime.MinValue;
```

It'll convert the `DateTime.MinValue`, which has a `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` kind, to UTC. This will throw the exception you show, because you're in a GMT+ timezone: it'll subtract your GMT offset from the `MinValue`, yielding an invalid value, as explained in [Converting DateTime.MinValue to DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924198/converting-datetime-minvalue-to-datetimeoffset).

The solution: use [`DateTimeOffset.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, don't use `try-catch` around `Parse(Exact)`; use `TryParse(Exact)`.

Comment: thank you, i used this DateTimeOffset.MinValue but i cant use birthDatePicker.Date = DateTime.MinValue; the exception occurred again when i write this line after my code birthDatePicker.Date = DateTime.MinValue;

Comment: Yeah because you should use `birthDatePicker.Date = DateTimeOffset.MinValue`.

Comment: Again, create a [mcve]. From your description it is unclear what you're trying to do. `DateTimeOffset someDateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.MinValue` will compile and run just fine.

Comment: Correct. Here is the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.op_implicit.aspx) for that `implicit operator`. The asker should have included a stack trace; then the cause would have been easier to determine.